# Publish Website Using csproj file

Tags: msbuild

**[UPDATE]** Fixed it (will answer later when StackOverflow lets me) but basically I installed "Web Deployment Projects" which is a free addon for VS2010. Then, in my Web Proejct itself, right click and add 'Add New Web Deployment Project'. When that builds, in the output folder, it dumps a complete version of a deployable webapp (DLLS, Views, Controllers, Images etc etc). Then, you can start getting clever with configuration settings, by having separate configs for production, test, development etc. Basically, I followed the instructions here http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2010/05/09/automated-site-deployments-with-teamcity-deployment-projects-amp-svn (excellent article)

----- My Original Post ---------

I've got a solution with a web (MVC3) project, and numerous other projects. I'm using TeamCity to build my solution by pointing it at the sln files (rather than build scripts).

At the end of each build, I want a couple of artifacts remaining, that are: a version of the website for my test environment and a version for my production environment.

I understand about making build configurations (web.config), but I'm struggling to understand what I need to do to my csproj files (the default build scripts) to publish these different versions of the website (to a folder on the build server, not a server/online).

I think I need to add something to the

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">  
     (something goes here)
  </Target>
```

...part of my csproj file (presumably the one in the web project) but despite plenty of searching, I can't get the right syntax. I think I need something like

```
<MSBuild Target="Publish" ...>
```

...but I'm getting very confused with it all.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

Comment: Actually, although I got it working, I can replace values such as 'appSettings' using the replacement feature, but I also have a config section called 'spring' in my Web.config, and it doesn't seem to let me replace that (possibly because it's a user-defined config section). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my update, I ended up using Web Deployment Projects and it works fine (apart from a very annoying problem with web.config replacements)